Best Places to Visit in Agadir and Marrakech, Morocco?
I’m planning a trip to Morocco starting in Agadir and maybe going to Marrakech after. Can you recommend the best places to visit in agadir and marrakech ?
Thanks!

Sorry, we don't know what 'best' means for you, so this question will likely be closed. If you have any specific questions, feel free to ask. In the mean time, you can read this

This is a question that is easily answered by a simple internet search. Best things in (add name of town.)
